# Dark theme and light theme problem - android studio (night)

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I will try to explain in detail‚ please help. I opened a new project‚ in the new project the "theme" section was opened twice‚ one light one dark. I added black text to the app ‚the text looked white because my phone is a dark theme. This is very good but incomprehensible. I only have one color.xml file (not for the night version) How did the text change to white? This is fine but the icon (vector ‚xml) I added and gave it a gray color ‚but now it was incomprehensible. The color of the icon changed from gray to black in the dark. I wanted him to change to white. I also opened for Colors.xml for the night. Now that I think there will be no mistakes, nothing has changed. The night is getting black in them.

1. How can I make an icon (vector ‚xml) gray in light and white in the dark theme?
2. I have a dark and light "theme" file ‚Do I have to separate the "colors" into dark and light themes?

I hope I was able to explain ‚Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you have to keep two instances of that icon, one dark, one light. Keep a check on your android theme https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#config-changes Use the ?android:attr/colorBackground theme attribute instead. Note that dark-themed android:windowBackground drawables only work on Android 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text's color has changed to white because you didn't set a color, and it's inherits from the default android settings.

If you want to change (customise) the colors depending on the theme, I suggest you to override the colors.xml file for the night mode.

Declare the color that you want for your icon.

**colors.xml**

```xml
  <color name="iconColor">#FF808080</color>
```

**colors.xml (night)**

```xml
  <color name="iconColor">#FFFFFFF</color>
```

In your drawable, you must set this new color.

```xml
 android:fillColor="@color/iconColor"
```

It's also a good thing to override the others colors (primary, primaryLight, etc.) to lighter variants.

You can practice [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-2%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme#0) if you want to exercise the theme changed on android (this is in Kotlin, but the same course exists in Java).